# Extract files from zip archive excluding certain filenames

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

In Python, how do I extract a zip archive while preserving folder structure but excluding certain filenames (file types) from extraction? For example, I want to exclude all the `.tif` images from being extracted.

I'm using Python 3.x and the `zipfile` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a filtered `members` to `extractall()`. `archive.extractall(members=(member for member in archive.namelist() if not member.endswith('.tif')))`.

```
def extractall(self, path=None, members=None, pwd=None):
    """Extract all members from the archive to the current working
       directory. `path' specifies a different directory to extract to.
       `members' is optional and must be a subset of the list returned
       by namelist().
    """
    if members is None:
        members = self.namelist()

    for zipinfo in members:
        self.extract(zipinfo, path, pwd)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is been a while since I have used this routine, so I had to dig it out.
You may want to test/adapt to your specific need.

The exclusion `if` statement only checks the last three characters of the to be extracted file name, you can change this using a `.split('.')` to check for the full extension as many files now have more than 3 characters for extension.

This was written for Windows, and you may want to change certain bits if running on other OSs

This code is preserving the folder structure, but probably not the fastest routine (although I never had any complaints:

```
import zipfile


def unzip_file(zippedfile = '', targetdir = '', exclude_ext = ''):

    if zippedfile == '': ## this is the .zip file
        return
    if targetdir == '':
        targetdir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(zippedfile), os.path.basename(zippedfile)[:-4])    
    if not os.path.exists (targetdir):
        os.makedirs (targetdir)

    zfile = zipfile.ZipFile(zippedfile)

    for name in zfile.namelist():
        (dirName, fileName) = os.path.split(name)
        if not dirName == '':
            if not os.path.exists (os.path.join(targetdir, dirName)):
                os.makedirs (os.path.join(targetdir, dirName))
        if fileName == '':
            # directory
            newDir = os.path.join(targetdir, dirName)
            if not os.path.exists(newDir):
                os.makedirs (newDir)
        else:
            # file
            if exclude_ext == '':
                print ('Extracting File : ' + name)
                fd = open(os.path.join(targetdir, name), 'wb')
                fd.write(zfile.read(name))
                fd.close()
            else:
                if not exclude_ext == name[-3:]:
                    print ('Extracting File : ' + name)
                    fd = open(os.path.join(targetdir, name), 'wb')
                    fd.write(zfile.read(name))
                    fd.close()                    
                else:
                    print ('File with extension ' + exclude_ext + ' is excluded')
    zfile.close()

    return
```

Good Luck.

Comment: Shouldn't use `print` here.

Comment: @BeauBarker why not, besides the point that I clearly say that you could adapt to your needs, so anyone using the above code could modify it and omit 'print'.

Comment: better to use the logging module which outputs to stderr, if you must log